# Swapping user control in a window upon selected item of list box, tree view or combobox

Tags: .net, wpf, user-controls, listbox

Swapping user control in a window upon selected item of list box, tree view or combo box .NET Framework

Answer (score 0):

List:

```
  <ListBox x:Name="l1"  ItemsSource="{Binding List}"></ListBox>
```

Multiple Usercontrols loded but will be displayed by visibility that will be selcted by list box "l1" selected item. "First" and "Second" are the values of the list.

```
         <vm:UserControl1 >
            <vm:UserControl1.Style>
                <Style TargetType="UserControl">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />

                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=l1}" Value="First">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </vm:UserControl1.Style>
        </vm:UserControl1>
        <vm:UserControl2 >
            <vm:UserControl2.Style>
                <Style TargetType="UserControl">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />

                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=l1}" Value="Second">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </vm:UserControl2.Style>
          </vm:UserControl2>
```

When u select fisrt usercontrol1 will be visible in the window when u select second usercontrol2 will be visible

[image: UserControl2]

[image: UserControl1]